# Cross validation on bootstrap data

Tags: cross-validation, bootstrap, validation, rms, dirichlet-distribution

I am performing a dirichlet model for different species using a small sample size (between 8 to 20 samples per each).

Since my dataset is small, I bootstrap my data with 1000 iterations, averaging 3 random selected individuals with replacement each time, creating a new dataset per species with 1000 "samples" (where each line corresponds to an averaged pseudo-animal).

Now I want to validate each species model.
I want to perform either a simple cross validation or a LOOV, however I am unsure if it is ok to perform it using the bootstrap data. Also, regarding the metrics to evaluate model performance, should I use the RMSE?

I would appreciate some input regarding these two doubts.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why $3$ for the bootstrap rather than the actual size of the sample you are applying the bootstrap too?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you mean averaging the total individuals in the sample in each iteration? Then I would get a new dataset where each line would be equal

Comment: My understanding is that if bootstrapping from a dataset of $n$ observations, best practice is to take samples sized $n$ *with replacement* from that dataset many times